# Simulating a FULL OUTER JOIN in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to join two tables and get the output as follows

```
T1

S    B   C   P
---  --  --  --
ABC  B1  C1  10
ABC  B2  C2  11
ABC  B3  C3  12

T2

S    B   C   P
---  --  --  --
ABC  B1  C1  12
ABC  B2  C2  13
ABC  B5  C5  14
```

I need the below output

```
S    B   C   P1  P2
---  --  --  --  --
ABC  B1  C1  10  12
ABC  B2  C2  11  13
ABC  B3  C3  12  0
ABC  B5  C5  0   14
```

Please note: I am using Microsoft Access and Access SQL does not directly support FULL OUTER JOIN queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    T1.S, T1.B, T1.C, T1.P AS P1, IIF(ISNULL(T2.P), 0, T2.P) AS P2 
FROM
    T1 LEFT JOIN
    T2 ON (T1.S = T2.S AND T1.B = T2.B AND T1.C = T2.C)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    T2.S, T2.B, T2.C, IIF(ISNULL(T1.P), 0, T1.P) AS P1, T2.P AS P2 
FROM
    T2 LEFT JOIN
    T1 ON (T1.S = T2.S AND T1.B = T2.B AND T1.C = T2.C)
WHERE T1.S IS NULL
```

Comment: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'T1.P P1'."

Comment: @GordThompson `AS` is apparently required for aliases. See update

Comment: It's returning `Null`s instead of `0`s as in the question, but otherwise OK. +1

Comment: @GordThompson I've forgotten about that. You can use `ISNULL` to achieve that. See update.

Comment: "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'ISNULL(T2.P,0'."

Comment: I've mistaken `ISNULL` with `IFNULL` from SQL server. I don't have access to access right now, so I'm guesing a bit. Try `IIF(ISNULL(T1.P), 0, T1.P)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s,
       b,
       c,
       SUM(temp_p1) as p1,
       SUM(temp_p2) as p2
  FROM (
         SELECT t1.s, 
                t1.b, 
                t1.c, 
                t1.p as temp_p1, 
                0 as temp_p2 
           FROM t1
      UNION ALL
         SELECT t2.s, 
                t2.b, 
                t2.c, 
                0 as temp_p1, 
                t2.p as temp_p2 
           FROM t2
       )
GROUP BY s,
         b,
         c
```

Comment: try now, there was a missing comma

Comment: "Circular reference caused by alias 'p1' in query definition's SELECT list."

Comment: try now Gord, otherwise I'll open access to check this query

Comment: "Enter Parameter Value [temp_p1]:"

Comment: fixed, do you know that you can edit an answer to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    T1.S, T1.B, T1.C, T1.P P1, T2.P P2 
FROM
    T1 left outer JOIN
    T2 ON (T1.S = T2.S AND T1.B = T2.B AND T1.C = T2.C)
UNION 
SELECT 
    T2.S, T2.B, T2.C, T1.P P1, T2.P P2 
FROM
    T2 LEFT outer JOIN
    T1 ON (T1.S = T2.S AND T1.B = T2.B AND T1.C = T2.C)
WHERE T1.S IS NULL
```

Comment: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'T1.P P1'."