# "Join Expression Not Supported" - Need help on Microsoft Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need some help making the following SQL code work:

```
SELECT MemberData.MemberID, Transaction.TrxID, Transaction.Date, 
Transaction.GroupID, TransactionDetails.CashIn, TransactionDetails.CashOut

FROM [Transaction] 
INNER JOIN (MemberData LEFT JOIN TransactionDetails 
            ON MemberData.[MemberID] = TransactionDetails.[MemberID]) 
ON Transaction.[TrxID] = TransactionDetails.[TrxID];
```

An error stating below keeps popping up:

> Join Expression Not Supported"

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: @Parfait that basically was my answer before the edit (+ reformatting the join to be more clear, because I don't like the weird first list all the tables and then all the on clauses that Access does), and unfortunately, that wasn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't pinpoint the exact source of the error, but a simple fix for most of the `Join expression not supported` errors is to do one join at a time, and use subqueries.

```sql
 SELECT MemberData.MemberID, T.TrxID, T.[Date], 
T.GroupID, T.CashIn, T.CashOut
FROM (
    SELECT [Transaction].TrxID, [Transaction].Date, [Transaction].GroupID, TransactionDetails.CashIn, TransactionDetails.CashOut, TransactionDetails.[MemberID]
     FROM [Transaction] 
     LEFT JOIN TransactionDetails  ON [Transaction].[TrxID] = TransactionDetails.[TrxID]
) AS T
INNER JOIN MemberData ON MemberData.[MemberID] = T.[MemberID];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! However, I still get the same error using your code

Comment: Try the current edit. This one uses a subquery, so it might be a bit slower, but will work.

Comment: Its asking me to enter a parameter "T.TransactionDetails.TrxID'?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was a minor mistake on my part. See edit

Comment: It ran without errors, but the results aren't what I intended. I was planning to use left join on tables "MemberData" and "TransactionDetails" on the field "MemberID". I would like the query to display all the available MemberIDs from the same GroupID even if some MemberIDs are not in the table "TransactionDetails". I would like to thank you for your really swift reply :)

Comment: Well, then you will have to rewrite the query in a major way. This is exactly what your query would do if it would run, you're running an `INNER JOIN` on that `MemberData` table (you can just use a `LEFT JOIN`, but that won't fix it. If you want all information from `MemberData`, you will need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but you can't do that in access. You can work around that using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976692/simulating-a-full-outer-join-in-access), but that isn't easy.

Comment: I see.. Thank you so much for your help, I greatly appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

@Poomind @Erik von Asmuth Just change the `INNER JOIN` into `RIGHT JOIN` You could try pasting the next SQL-statement into a new query.

```sql
SELECT MemberData.MemberID, T.TrxID, T.[Date], T.GroupID, T.CashIn, T.CashOut
```

```
FROM (SELECT [Transaction].TrxID, [Transaction].Date, [Transaction].GroupID,
             TransactionDetails.CashIn, TransactionDetails.CashOut, TransactionDetails.[MemberID]
     FROM [Transaction] 
     LEFT JOIN TransactionDetails  ON [Transaction].[TrxID] = TransactionDetails.[TrxID])
 AS T RIGHT JOIN MemberData ON MemberData.[MemberID] = T.[MemberID];
```

When I saved this query in a sample database, ms-access (version 2003) changed it to the following SQL-statement. So, don't worry if this happens with you too.

```sql
SELECT MemberData.MemberID, T.TrxID, T.[Date], T.GroupID, T.CashIn, T.CashOut
FROM [SELECT [Transaction].TrxID, [Transaction].Date, [Transaction].GroupID, TransactionDetails.CashIn, TransactionDetails.CashOut, TransactionDetails.[MemberID]
     FROM [Transaction] 
     LEFT JOIN TransactionDetails  ON [Transaction].[TrxID] = TransactionDetails.[TrxID]
]. AS T RIGHT JOIN MemberData ON MemberData.[MemberID] = T.[MemberID];
```

Comment: @Wilson-Vargas Thanx for the change to language_sql!

Comment: That will return a syntax error. (you did some weird things with replacing braces `()` with brackets `[]` and `TransactionDetails.[TrxID]].AS T ` is also not valid SQL). Of course, you can change the `INNER JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN` in my answer, but then the transaction information may be incomplete. The only way to have both everything from `MemberData` and from `Transaction` is a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which is unsupported.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Indeed, I deleted a space: `TrxID]].AS T` must be `Trx]]. AS T`. About the replaced braces `()` and brackets `[]`: as mentioned, it is MsAccess (version 2003) who produced this. About the syntax error, I am able to produce him too. Perhaps I should create a seperate question about this phenomenon?

Comment: Not really a reason to open a separate thread in my opinion. Just replace the square brackets with braces here: `FROM [SELECT` and here: `]. AS ` and remove the dot from the latest, just like in my answer. Then it will work.